# can I have $\det(A+B)=0$ if $\det(A)=0$ and $\det(B) \neq 0$?

Tags: determinant, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Given two square matrix $A$ and $B$ that $\det(A)=0$ and $\det(B) \neq 0$. Is it possibly that $\det(A+B)=0$ ?

I have tried numerically, it seems that this is impossible. However I don't know how to prove it because there is no relation between $\det(A+B)=0$ and $\det(A)$, $\det(B)$.

Comment: ok got it, I did try with random matrix. My question is clearly wrong. I upvote you all. Thank everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
1&1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Consider

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B=I_2$$

Answer (score 2):

Try $A= \matrix {0&1\\0&0}, B=\matrix {1&0\\1&1}$

Answer (score 2):

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $B = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$